# AAPT : error : unexpected element <library> found in <manifest> I tried cloning a github sample project to be run but couldnt because of this error

Tags: android, azure, manifest, aapt

**ERROR SHOWN:**
C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\Cognitive-Emotion-Android\Sample\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in .

**THIS IS MY MANIFEST CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.microsoft.projectoxford.emotionsample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <library /> *this line is the problem*
    <library>
    </library>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.microsoft.projectoxford.emotionsample.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.microsoft.projectoxford.emotionsample.RecognizeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_analyze"
            android:parentActivityName="com.microsoft.projectoxford.emotionsample.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.microsoft.projectoxford.emotionsample.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.microsoft.projectoxford.emotionsample.helper.SelectImageActivity"
            android:label="@string/select_an_image"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: remove `<library /> *this line is the problem*
    <library>
    </library>`